# Displaying mailitem generates Runtime Error -2147467259

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I loop through a MailItem collection to display the MailItem if the conversationID is the same as the request.

However, *it seems*, when the item searched is not on the ActiveSelection and the MailItem.Display function is called it produces the 'Runtime Error -2147467259'

> Outlook can't do this because a dialog box is open. Please close it and try again.

Here is the code

```
'  email_link_Click()                                                                   '
'           -> Compares the ConversationID sent through to get the email                '
Sub email_link_Click()
    Dim searchFolder As Object

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set searchFolder = olFldr

    If Not Me.email_folder.Caption = "Inbox" Then
       Set searchFolder = olFldr.Folders(Me.email_folder.Caption)
    End If

    searchFolder.Items.Sort "[Subject]", False

    For Each emailvar In searchFolder.Items
        If emailvar.ConversationID = Me.conversationID_label.Caption Then
            FilingPrint ("Found email - Opening..")
            emailvar.Display '<- Error is created from here
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next emailvar

    Set searchFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is this because it cannot view two email's at once?

Comment: Perhaps explicitly defining you email items might help, e.g.: Dim emailvar As Outlook.MailItem, which would require adding a reference to your most recent Microsoft Outlook library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the issue was that effectively I had 2 instances of the view opened. Instead of spending too much time on it, I created a user-form that looks like an email view and pulled the details from a parsed MailItem object.